# How does one access an image inside div element in jquery for uploading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, uploading

How would I go about accessing an image inside a div of elements?

There are a bunch of div's in the frames div.

How would one programmatically access a specific div element, based on the onclick button.upload_image method?

...

```
 <div id="frames">
     <div style="width:100px;">
       <img src="blob:http://localhost/57330ba5-938c-46de-91bd-4f65b0eb156d" id="images" width="100px" height="100px">
       <button type="button" class="upload_image" id="0">Upload</button>&nbsp;
       <button type="button" class="remove_image">X</button>
     </div>
     <div style="width:100px;">
       <img src="blob:http://localhost/57330ba5-938c-41de-90bd-4f65b0eb156d" id="images" width="100px" height="100px">
       <button type="button" class="upload_image" id="0">Upload</button>&nbsp;
       <button type="button" class="remove_image">X</button>
     </div>
     <div style="width:100px;">
       <img src="blob:http://localhost/57330ba5-938c-46de-91bd-4f65b0eb156d" id="images" width="100px" height="100px">
       <button type="button" class="upload_image" id="0">Upload</button>&nbsp;
       <button type="button" class="remove_image">X</button>
     </div>
 </div>


 $('#frames')
  .on('click', 'button.upload_image', function() {
    // how to access the image via this method?

  });
```

...